# macOS Swift Apps uncompilable with exit 1 signal 0

Tags: swift, xcode, macos-sierra

I am currently developing two macOS applications, and both of them were bug free until about 9:00 PM on Tuesday, October 4 when both applications all of a sudden were unable to be compiled due to `error: Task failed with exit 1 signal 0`. Both apps point to this file: `libswiftAppKit.dylib` inside their respective debugging directories (which are different). I have tried deleting the file from the debugging directory, I have tried to reset my keychain, I have setup a provisioning profile, I have cleaned both projects many times, and I have restarted my computer twice.

Edit: It is still not working, and I have uninstalled and reinstalled Xcode.

Edit 2: I have reinstalled macOS Sierra and the same error is on both of my apps.

Why is this happening (also, why is it "all of a sudden" for two separate apps)? How do I fix it?

Comment: This is just a wild guess, have you tried upgrading or reinstalling `xcode`?

Comment: I have not, I was hoping for easier solution since installing xCode takes hours. Also, one thing to note is that iOS apps are compiling fine, it's only macOS apps that are not working

Comment: Here's a discussion forum you might want to watch https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7679585?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Are you still running xcode 7.3 or are you already at 8.0?

Comment: Xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY FIGURED IT OUT!

After many many hours, I finally went back into my developer account's certificates/profiles and deleted everything and recreated each one. Installed them onto my Mac, and now it is finally working. Still don't understand why all of a sudden this happened, but that was my solution.

Comment: If that was the solution, it means that the application suddenly lost the certificates' signature? Either it expired or Apple has changed signing certificate. I know certificates affect whether apps can be installed or not, but am not aware that it affect compilation. Good catch though and thanks for posting the solution.

Comment: I encourage you to post your findings in apple developers forum as well.